# How would I find the max value of objects in ArrayList in for-loop? -Java

Tags: java, class, object, for-loop, arraylist

So it seems that both my methods in my Persons class are giving me the wrong information. I have two methods called get `totalSalary()` and `maxSalary()` that go through ArrayList personList and calculate the total salary or all the objects and then another one finds the max salary. Here is my Persons class that contains all my attempts at finding max and total:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Persons {

public ArrayList<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<Person>();

public boolean addPerson(Person newPerson) {
    personsList.add(newPerson);
    return true;
}


public double totalSalary() {
    double salary = 0;
    for(Person person : personsList) {
        salary += person.getJob().getSalary();
    }
    return salary;
}


public double maxSalary() {
    double max = 0.0;
    for(Person person : personsList) {
        if(person.getJob().getSalary() > max) {
            max = person.getJob().getSalary();
        }
     }
    return max;
 }

}
```

Here is my main where i created the object, add the info and call my methods:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class testPersons {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Persons persons = new Persons();

    Address person1Address = new Address(1052, "Sum St", "San Francisco", "CA", "94544");
    Address person1JobAddress = new Address(1542, "High St", "Santa Cruz", "CA", "94063");
    ArrayList<String> person1Phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    person1Phone.add("650-555-555");
    Job person1Job = new Job("Teacher", 10000.00, person1JobAddress);
    Person person1 = new Person("Dylan Johnson", "San Mateo", 'M', person1Address, person1Job, person1Phone);

    Address person2Address = new Address(1054, "Pico St", "Los Angeles", "CA", "97556");
    Address person2JobAddress = new Address(5435, "James St", "Redwood City", "CA", "94063");
    ArrayList<String> person2Phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    person2Phone.add("555-555-555");
    Job person2Job = new Job("Mechanic", 20000.00, person2JobAddress);
    Person person2 = new Person("Rollan Tico", "New York", 'M', person2Address, person2Job, person2Phone);

    Address person3Address = new Address(517, "A St", "Redwood City", "CA", "94063");
    Address person3JobAddress = new Address(519, "Bing St", "San Carlos", "CA", "94064");
    ArrayList<String> person3Phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    person3Phone.add("555-555-555");
    Job person3Job = new Job("Janitor", 5000.00, person2JobAddress);
    Person person3 = new Person("Dwayne Rock", "San Jose", 'M', person2Address, person2Job, person2Phone);

    persons.addPerson(person1);
    persons.addPerson(person2);
    persons.addPerson(person3);

    System.out.printf("The total salaries: "+ persons.totalSalary() + "\n");
    System.out.printf("The max salary: " + persons.maxSalary() + "\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: How are getJob() & getSalary() implemented? Can you please share?

Comment: Can you tell us your expected output and your actual output please?

Comment: Using the [builder pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) would have prevented this typo-relegated error from happening.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the person2 data for persons 2 and 3.

Change

```
Person person3 = new Person("Dwayne Rock", "San Jose", 'M', person2Address, person2Job, person2Phone);
```

To:

```
Person person3 = new Person("Dwayne Rock", "San Jose", 'M', person3Address, person3Job, person3Phone);
```

Comment: That would make the total wrong, but it wouldn't make the maximum wrong.  OP claims that both are  wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working perfect except the wrong variable assignment for person3, check below.

```
public class testPersons {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Persons persons = new Persons();

    Address person1Address = new Address(1052, "Sum St", "San Francisco", "CA", "94544");
    Address person1JobAddress = new Address(1542, "High St", "Santa Cruz", "CA", "94063");
    ArrayList<String> person1Phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    person1Phone.add("650-555-555");
    Job person1Job = new Job("Teacher", 10000.00, person1JobAddress);
    Person person1 = new Person("Dylan Johnson", "San Mateo", 'M', person1Address, person1Job, person1Phone);

    Address person2Address = new Address(1054, "Pico St", "Los Angeles", "CA", "97556");
    Address person2JobAddress = new Address(5435, "James St", "Redwood City", "CA", "94063");
    ArrayList<String> person2Phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    person2Phone.add("555-555-555");
    Job person2Job = new Job("Mechanic", 20000.00, person2JobAddress);
    Person person2 = new Person("Rollan Tico", "New York", 'M', person2Address, person2Job, person2Phone);

    Address person3Address = new Address(517, "A St", "Redwood City", "CA", "94063");
    Address person3JobAddress = new Address(519, "Bing St", "San Carlos", "CA", "94064");
    ArrayList<String> person3Phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    person3Phone.add("555-555-555");
    Job person3Job = new Job("Janitor", 5000.00, person3JobAddress);
    Person person3 = new Person("Dwayne Rock", "San Jose", 'M', person3Address, person3Job, person3Phone);

    persons.addPerson(person1);
    persons.addPerson(person2);
    persons.addPerson(person3);

    System.out.printf("The total salaries: "+ persons.totalSalary() + "\n");
    System.out.printf("The max salary: " + persons.maxSalary() + "\n");
  }
}
```